# codeigniter debug result in different computer

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two computers, one pc and one again laptop. 
Both have same version of mozila firefox.

In my laptop, I can access session->userdata in all classes of controller.

However, in my pc, I can access the session only in the class where I have set the session. In another class, I can't access it.

This thing also happen with facebook api php sdk. 
In my pc, I can var_dump the user login detail, in my laptop it always bool false.

I am very sure if the problem is not the php version of each computer because the server of the site is in vps.

I am confuse how to debug and to solve this kind of problem. Can anyone help, please.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Laptop/Desktop - OS, Codeigniter versions in both, FB SDK versions in both, PHP version itself in both?

Comment: I am using codeigniter 2.0 and windows seven in both computer.

Comment: the server of the site is in vps so the problem is not the php version, right?